# How do I display data from my JSON object coming from Server on page load itself in angular 5

Tags: json, angular, angular5

Currently, what I've implemented is getting data from JSON object when clicked on a button in HTML page.

From my TS File

```
getData() {
    this.httpSvc.getConfig()
      .subscribe((data) => {
        this.dataFromSever = data;
      })
  }
```

In HTML page:

```
<button (click)="getData()">Get Data</button>
<h3>List of users</h3>
<li *ngFor="let data of dataFromSever.users">{{data.username}}</li>
```

How can I display user's data on page load itself. I've searched online help but no luck. Any suggestions or ways to implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at Angular's [lifecycle hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks).

In your case `OnInit` would be appropriate. This function is called, when a component is created.

> An [ngOnInit](https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit)() is a good place for a component to fetch its initial data.

```
class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {
   this.getData();
  }
```

Comment: Awesome and perfect! This is what I needed.